# formating UK mobile to international number with Zapier Code Javascript function

Tags: javascript, zapier

The scenario is...

A visitor comes to my landing page and completed the form, which included a telephone number.

Using Zapier I then pass that form data to ActiveCampaign.com using a "ZAP".

However as ActiveCampaign is in USA, they require the phone number formatting to international standard, instead of local UK.

Most numbers in UK are 07788990022

But it needs to be presented as +447788990022

So I need to use this built in function of Zapier listed below

https://zapier.com/help/code/

And need some Javascript code writing that will check the number

1. Is it valid UK mobile number? I.e. 11 digits
2. Remove all spaces, and trim
3. If 2nd character is a 7 then replace 1st character (which should be a 0) with +44

I really dont have any idea how to do this! I was hoping for a built in function on Zapier, but apparently not. Any ideas would be awesome!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

This seems like a pretty straightforward js question! This will be pretty "dumb" validation, but will work assuming the input is correct.

You'll have a code (javascript) step and set the input to be `phone`: input from step 1. Your code will look like this:

```
var ph = inputData.phone.replace(/\s+/g, '') // remove all whitespace from string

if (ph.length !== 11) {
  // invalid phone number. do nothing?
  return []
}

if (ph[1] === '7') {
  ph = '+44' + ph.substr(1)
}

return {formattedNumber: ph}
```